Closed form solution for bayesian linear regression with 2 responses?
I am thinking about first principles from the point of view of a frequentist moving from regression with 1 response to regression with 2 responses. Reflecting on that I am trying to figure out how to move a bayesian linear regression with 1 response to one with 2 responses.
Univariate OLS: Say that we are in the usual OLS setting with
$y = X\beta + \varepsilon$
In this case, $y$ is a length $n$ vector, $X$ is a $n \times p$ matrix. The frequentist, OLS solution is
$\hat{\beta} = (X^T X)^{-1} X^Ty$ and its covariance is $(X^T X)^{-1} \sigma^2 / (n-p)$
In the case of 2 responses, we have
$Y = X\beta + E$
In this case, $Y$ and $E$ are both a $n \times 2$ matrix. The frequentist solution is
$\hat{\beta} = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y$ and its covariance is $(X^T X)^{-1} \otimes \Sigma$ where $\otimes$ is the kronecker product and $\Sigma$ is estimated as $\hat{E}^T \hat{E}$, a $2 \times 2$ covariance matrix of the residuals. The upper right corner of $\hat{E}^T \hat{E}$ shows how the 2 responses are correlated.
In the bayesian linear regression with 1 response and with a gaussian prior, there is also a closed form solution. Say that $\sigma^2$ is fixed. The prior is normally distributed with mean $\beta_0$ and prior covariance $\Sigma_0$.
Then the posterior is
\begin{align}
p(\beta | X, y) &= N(\beta_N, \Sigma_N) \\
\Sigma_N &= (\Sigma_0^{-1} + \frac{1}{\sigma^2} X^T X)^{-1} \\
\beta_N &= \Sigma_N (\Sigma_0^{-1} \beta_0 + \frac{1}{\sigma^2} X^T X \beta)
\end{align}
Is there a natural extension of this algebraic solution when $Y$ is a 2 column response matrix? I am especially stuck on whether there is an algebraic counterpart to the frequentist solution that used the kronecker product to model the upper right corner of the covariance matrix, which reflects the correlation between responses

Hi: A 2 column response matrix doesn't make sense to me. Are you possibly referring to multivariate regression ? My guess is that others are confused also since there were no responses.

A Gaussian prior is equivalent to ridge regression and at least the maximum of the posterior distribution (which is equal to the mean of that distribution) has an easy solution. I am sure that the variance should have an easy solution as well.

Let $y_i^\top$ be a row vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$, $x_i^\top$ be a row vector in $\mathbb{R}^k$, and let:
$$
y_i^\top = x_i^\top B + \epsilon_i^\top,\quad \epsilon_i^\top\sim \operatorname{N}_m(0_m,\Sigma),
$$
where $\operatorname{N}_m$ represents the $m$-dimensional multivariate Gaussian distribution, and $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ is an outcome-covariance matrix.
Let $Y\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ be matrices containing, as row-entries, $n$ independent samples from $y_i^\top$ and $x_i^\top$ respectively.
Then one has that, with such $n$ samples, and for known $\Sigma$ and conjugate multivariate Gaussian prior:
$$
\operatorname{vec}(B)\sim \operatorname{N}_m(\operatorname{vec}(B_0),\Sigma\otimes\Omega_0),
$$
with hyper-parameters $B_0\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times m}$ and $\Omega_0\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$, the  posterior is also multivariate Gaussian:
$$
\operatorname{vec}(B)\mid X,Y\sim \operatorname{N}_m(\operatorname{vec}(B_n),\Sigma\otimes(X^\top X+\Omega_0^{-1})^{-1}),
$$
with
$$
B_n = (X^\top X+\Omega_0^{-1})^{-1}(X^\top Y+\Omega_0^{-1}B_0).
$$
Here $\Omega_0$ is the hyper-prior parameter for the covariance matrix among rows of $B$, i.e. among the coefficients of covariates. For a more convenient notation, the prior can be expressed using a precision matrix instead $\Lambda_0=\Omega_0^{-1}$.
If $\Sigma$ is not known, but has an Inverse-Wishart distribution prior, conjugacy is still in place, and the posterior is given here.
